# Select all elements with a particular id and a missing attribute

Tags: jquery

The html I am working with has tags something like:

```
<a id="tag" data="modal" href=#>1</a>
<a id="tag" data="modal" href=#>2</a>
<a id="abc" href=#>8</a>
<a id="tag" href=#>3</a>
<a id="tag" data="modal" href=#>4</a>
<a id="tag" href=#>5</a>
<a id="tag" href=#>6</a>
<a id="tag" data="modal" href=#>7</a>
```

I want to select all a elements with id=tag and missing data attribute. I tried using `$('a#tag[data!=modal]')` but it returned only the first matching element. When I tried `$('a[data!=modal]')`, it returns all the a elements with missing data attribute along with a `id="abc"`, which I don't want. Please advice.

EDIT: I know its not how an HTML is supposed to be structured but its not controlled by me and I'm stuck to implement analytics on it.

Comment: Ids must be unique on document context, use class instead... Now this would work but don't use it....: `$('a[id=tag]:not([data])')`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: In a page,one element can have one id only. It should be unique in your document.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks! this worked

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple HTML elements with the same IDs. Under the hood jQuery will be using `getElementById` which will return only the first element.

However you could change these to classes:

```
<a class="tag" data="modal" href=#>1</a>
```

Then your selector would be:

```
$(".tag:not([data])")
```